# How to remove folders from git untracked and not staged for commit that contain "build" keyword?

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I have a `git status` of a form below:

```
(base) L32888MEU:kmp-shared-tests-framework skwaj$ git status
On branch skwaj
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/skwaj'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/androidApp/build.gradle.kts
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/shared
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework/Headers/shared.h
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/shared.framework/shared
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/cinterop/shared-cinterop-DateTools.klib
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/cinterop/shared-cinterop-DateTools.klib-build/manifest.properties
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/cinterop/shared-cinterop-DateTools.klib-build/natives/cstubs.bc
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/klib/shared.klib
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/kmpsharedtestsframework/BuildConfig.java
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/packageDebugResources/compile-file-map.properties
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/debug/manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/debug/package-aware-r.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/libs/iosX64/main/shared-cinterop-DateTools.klib
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/shared.framework.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/shared.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/shared
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/shared.framework/Headers/shared.h
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/shared.framework/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/shared.framework/shared
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/klib/sharedInterfacesModule.klib
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/BuildConfig.java
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/packageDebugResources/compile-file-map.properties
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/BuildConfig.class
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/debug/manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/debug/package-aware-r.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/inputs/source-to-output.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/inputs/source-to-output.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/inputs/source-to-output.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/inputs/source-to-output.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/inputs/source-to-output.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-attributes.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-attributes.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-attributes.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-attributes.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-fq-name-to-source.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-fq-name-to-source.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-fq-name-to-source.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-fq-name-to-source.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/class-fq-name-to-source.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/internal-name-to-source.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/internal-name-to-source.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/internal-name-to-source.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/internal-name-to-source.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/internal-name-to-source.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/proto.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/proto.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/proto.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/proto.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/proto.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/source-to-classes.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/source-to-classes.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/source-to-classes.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/source-to-classes.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/source-to-classes.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/subtypes.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/supertypes.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/supertypes.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/supertypes.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/supertypes.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/jvm/kotlin/supertypes.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/file-to-id.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/file-to-id.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/file-to-id.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/file-to-id.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/id-to-file.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/id-to-file.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab.keystream
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab.keystream.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab.len
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab.values.at
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/caches-jvm/lookups/lookups.tab_i
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/cacheable/last-build.bin
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/kotlin/compileDebugKotlinAndroid/local-state/build-history.bin
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/previous-compilation-data.bin
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/IAppLauncher$DefaultImpls.class
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/IAppLauncher.class
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/IAppUIElement$DefaultImpls.class
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/IAppUIElement.class
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/example/sharedinterfacesmodule/IAppWrapper.class
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/sharedTestsModule.framework.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/sharedTestsModule.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/sharedTestsModule
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/sharedTestsModule.framework/Headers/sharedTestsModule.h
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/sharedTestsModule.framework/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/bin/iosX64/debugFramework/sharedTestsModule.framework/sharedTestsModule
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/classes/kotlin/iosX64/main/klib/sharedTestsModule.klib
    deleted:    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/example/sharedtestsmodule/BuildConfig.java
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/aapt_friendly_merged_manifests/debug/aapt/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/packageDebugResources/compile-file-map.properties
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/debug/manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/output-metadata.json
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/sharedTestsModule.framework.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/sharedTestsModule.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/sharedTestsModule
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/sharedTestsModule.framework/Headers/sharedTestsModule.h
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/sharedTestsModule.framework/Info.plist
    modified:   KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator15.5/sharedTestsModule.framework/sharedTestsModule

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/androidApp/build/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/.transforms/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/pega/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/aar_metadata/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugJniLibFolders/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugShaders/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/incremental/packageDebugAssets/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/javac/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/library_java_res/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/navigation_json/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_dir/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/kotlin/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/tmp/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/shared/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/.transforms/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/pega/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/pega/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/navigation_json/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_dir/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedInterfacesModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/pega/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/.transforms/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/pega/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/annotations_typedef_file/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes_jar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/compile_symbol_list/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/incremental/debug-mergeJavaRes/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/javac/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/library_java_res/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/merged_java_res/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/navigation_json/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_dir/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/kotlin/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/outputs/aar/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/tmp/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/
    KMPSharedTestsFramework/sharedTestsModule/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I would like to remove EVERY folder that contains `build` subfolder in it, but I only want to remove it from index, not from my disk, local storage. I want to remove these build folders because they are too big and I don't want them in my repo. I want to remove them, then add them to the .gitignore.

I have tried running `` git rm -r --cached `find . -name build` `` but it throws an error: `fatal: pathspec './KMPSharedTestsFramework/build' did not match any files`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Hint: `find . -name build -type d | sed 's!/build$!!'`

Comment: @phd Thank you!!! That did the trick, but can you explain what that part after the pipeline does? It looks pretty confusing to me...

Comment: The command `sed`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed . Its program `s!/build$!!` means "search `/build` at the end of the string (`$`) and replace with empty string"; this removes `/build` from all found results.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Kotlin? (The Gradle config file is written in the Kotlin DSL — but to git it's all just files; AFAICS, this question has no more to do with Kotlin than it does with Android, Gradle, XCode, ASCII, filesystems, or electricity…)